# Visualforce Error Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm getting this error, can anyone help? I've tried wrapping the code in an if clause to prevent the error but it's not helping. The error is on QWeekly1K:

declaring variables before the method:

```
public List<AggregateResult> totalWeekly1AggK {get;set;}
public List<Daily_Forecast__c> Weekly1ListK {get;set;}
public object totalWeekly1K {get;set;}
public String sWeekly1K {get;set;}
public Decimal QWeekly1K {get;set;}

public void showAll(){
        //get today's DAY to parse daily forecasts in table
        todayDay = DateTime.now().format('EEEE');     

totalWeekly1AggK = new List<AggregateResult>([SELECT SUM(Forecast_Amount__c) 
            FROM Daily_Forecast__c WHERE Date__c = THIS_WEEK AND Day__c = 'Monday' AND User__r.Team__c = 'KCM' AND RecordType.Name = 'Weekly Forecast' GROUP BY Date__c]);
        if(totalWeekly1AggK.size()>0){
            totalWeekly1K = totalWeekly1AggK[0].get('expr0');
            if (totalWeekly1K == null) {
               totalWeekly1K = 0;
            }
    if (integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K) > 0) {
        QWeekly1K = integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K);
    }

    if (QWeekly1K != Null) {
        if (totalWeekly1K == 0) {
            QWeekly1K=0;
        }

        if (integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K) == 0) {
            QWeekly1K = 0;
            sWeekly1K='0';
        }
    }

    if (QWeekly1K == NULL ){
        QWeekly1K=0;
    }

    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        newTotalK = 1;
        QTotalK=1;
    }

    if (QWeekly1K==NULL) {
        newTotalK=QTotalK;
    }

    if (QWeekly1K > 0) {
        if (todayDay == 'Monday' && QWeekly1K != NULL) {
            newTotalK = QWeekly1K + QTotalK;
        }

        sWeekly1K = String.format(QWeekly1K.format(), argsTotal);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Today is Tuesday so the error is in a new place, I've debugged and QTuesdayK is not null or 0, I don't understand the error

```
TuesdayListK = new List<Daily_Forecast__c>();
                    for(Daily_Forecast__c e :TuesdayList){
                        if(e.User__r.Team__c == 'KCM'){
                        TuesdayListK.add(e);}} 
    system.debug('TuesdayListK '+TuesdayListK);
    if(TuesdayListK.size()>0){        
        totalTuesdayAggK = new List<AggregateResult>([SELECT SUM(Forecast_Amount__c) 
                FROM Daily_Forecast__c WHERE Date__c = THIS_WEEK AND Day__c = 'Tuesday' AND User__r.Team__c = 'KCM' AND RecordType.Name = 'Daily Forecast' GROUP BY Date__c]);
            if(totalTuesdayAggK.size()>0){
            totalTuesdayK = totalTuesdayAggK[0].get('expr0');}
            if(integer.valueOf(totalTuesdayK)>0){
            QTuesdayK = integer.valueOf(totalTuesdayK);}
               if(integer.valueOf(totalTuesdayK)==0){
                    QTuesdayK=0;
                    sTuesdayK='0';
                }
        system.debug('totalTuesdayK '+totalTuesdayK);
            system.debug('QTuesdayK '+QTuesdayK);
            system.debug('sTuesdayK '+sTuesdayK);
            system.debug('newTotalK '+newTotalK);
            system.debug('QTotalK '+QTotalK);
            if(QTuesdayK>0){
                if(todayDay == 'Tuesday'){
                    newTotalK = 
                        QTuesdayK +   //this is the line that throws the error
                        QTotalK;}
                sTuesdayK = String.format(QTuesdayK.format(), argsTotal);}

    }         
     if(TuesdayListK.size()==0){sTuesdayK =NULL;}
```

[image: debugLog]

Comment: is `totalWeekly1K` null? can you put a system.debug in there? `Integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K) > 0` will throw an error if it's null.  Also where are you declaring `QWeekly1K`?  You are also not getting your aggregate result correct

Comment: What is the correct way to get the aggregate result? And if I set totalWeekly1K=0 why doesn't that resolve the error?

Comment: what are you trying to aggregate?

Comment: turn developermode on for the running user and it will tell you the line number

Comment: I'm trying to return the Sum of all forecasts for the given day. Today is tuesday so the error is in a different place in the code, I appended the original post above.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're wrong when you say the error is on QWeekly1K

**That error is provided by several of the built in methods that apex provides.** It most likely is caused by something like:

```
integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K);
```

Where the value of totalWeekly1k is null.

**Another common location is when trying to use math operators with null values**:

```
Integer i = 0 + null;
```

To troubleshoot this, expand your code to include debugs and identify where the null value is:

```
system.debug(totalWeekly1K);

if (integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K) > 0) {
    QWeekly1K = integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K);
}
```

To fix the issue you'll need to do a null check as the first item in your If Statement:

```
system.debug(totalWeekly1K);

if (totalWeekly1K != null && integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K) > 0) {
    QWeekly1K = integer.valueOf(totalWeekly1K);
}
```

This is just 1 example there could be other places in your code that can throw this error. You'll have to do some troubleshooting to isolate exactly where the error is and resolve it.

Alternatively you can put something like this at the top of your class:

```
if (totalWeekly1K == null) {
    totalWeekly1K = 0;
}
```

### Update:

Based on your debug, the error is because QTotalK is null and you're attempting to use it in a math equation. You need to set QTotalK to 0 before trying to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried both of your suggestions but still getting the error. I am declaring the variables at the beginning of the class before the method. I edited the original question to show this

Comment: @JeanGrey I think you didn't quite get the full scope of my answer. I gave you a few examples but I didn't tell you exactly where your error is. This can happen with many built in methods. The integer.value of was just the one I pulled from your example to make it relatable. This can also happen in your string.format method. You're going to have to do some work on this one.

Comment: I've debugged, the value of the integer is not null, why would the integer throw an error?

Comment: You're still not comprehending. The integer may not be causing the issue. Let me say that again, The integer may not be causing the issue. Do I need to say it again? I'm sorry yes that's rude, but apparently it's also necessary. Read every word I put in my answer and in my comments.

Comment: The visualforce page tells me which line has the error. It's the QWeekly1K/QTuesdayK. But in accordance with your sage advice I have debugged every single line of code in this section. results attached.

Comment: Your debug log shows exactly whats wrong. QTuesday K is not null, but QTotalK is null. You can't use an addition operator with a null parameter or you'll get the error you're seeing. Set QtotalK = 0 before trying to use it in the equation and you'll be fine. If this hops around, chances are it's because you use QTotalK more than once.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help. I set QTotalK earlier in the class, I added code to set to 0 if null and it's working now.

Comment: @JeanGrey Great! Sorry I had to get a little rude but I'm glad that it got you to where you needed to go. If this answer is correct, please remember to mark it as the correct answer so that other users will know that it worked for you.